# In outlook vba how can I find what datetime a mail item was read?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to be able to find out what time/date emails received in microsoft outlook were read.

I can't see that the information is saved by Outlook. Nor does it appear the LastModificationTime reflects this either - it isn't updated when an item is marked as read (at least in Outlook 2007)

Assuming this is correct, I have decided to store this information in the future, and created a userproperty to reflect this. I've hooked the mailitem.PropertyChange event handler with the following code, but it's not a very universal solution - I'll have to put the code into every Outlook app I use. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

This code in placed in the ThisOutlookSession module (and Outlook restarted)

```html
Private WithEvents objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Private WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set objExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub
 
Private Sub objExplorer_SelectionChange()
  If objExplorer.CurrentFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
    If objExplorer.Selection.count > 0 Then
      Set myItem = objExplorer.Selection(1)
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
'    Debug.Print Name & "=" & myItem.UnRead
    If Name = "UnRead" And myItem.UnRead = False Then
        Dim myProperty As Outlook.UserProperty
        Set myProperty = myItem.UserProperties("ReadTime")
        If (myProperty Is Nothing) Then Set myProperty = myItem.UserProperties.Add("ReadTime", olNumber)
        myProperty.Value = Now()
        myItem.Save
'        Debug.Print Format(myItem.UserProperties("ReadTime"), "hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yy")
    ElseIf Name = "UnRead" And myItem.UnRead = True Then
        myItem.UserProperties("ReadTime").Delete
    End If
'    Debug.Print
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything about the Read status (the time when it was marked as read).

VBA is not designed for distributing on multiple PCs. You need to develop an Outlook add-in instead. That's exactly for what they were introduced. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that - strictly speaking, read/unread state is not even part of the message: it is stored separately. And Exchange Public Folders store stores that state on the per-user basis.

If you set the user property, it will not be persisted unless you call Save, but that will change the last modification time.